Work in a two-compartment system
A well-insulated container of fixed volume is divided into two equal compartments by a thermally-conductive, weightless, frictionless piston. Initially, compartment A, on the left, contains 50 mol of air at 25C and 50 bar, and compartment B, on the right, contains air at 400 C and 5 bar. The piston is then allowed to slide.
I have solved for the number of moles of B (using the fact that the two volumes are initially equal), equilibrium temperature (using the fact that the total change in internal energy of the system must be zero), and equilibrium pressure (using the information about the final temperature, total volume, and number of moles of each gas). The piston moves to the right, and gas A expands, compressing gas B.
My confusion has to do with the work.
Gas A is compressing gas B, doing work on it; the work done by gas A (in compressing gas B) should be equal to the work done on gas B (to be compressed). Thus, $W_{A} = -W_{B}$, or $W_{A} + W_{B} = 0$.
However, it should also be true that $W_{A} = -\int_{}^{}P_{ext,A}dV_{A} = -\int_{}^{}P_{B}dV_{A}$, because the external pressure that A is expanding against is the pressure exerted by gas B. Similarly, $W_{B} = -\int_{}^{}P_{A}dV_{B}$. Because the total volume is fixed, $dV_{A} = -dV_{B}$. Thus, the total work, $W_{A} + W_{B} = −∫_{B}_{A} + ∫_{A}_{A} = ∫(_{A} - _{B})_{A}$. Because $_{A} > _{B}$, I'm struggling to square this with the above idea that $W_{A} + W_{B}$ should be zero.
Can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong? Is one of these two assumptions flawed?

The two compartments are not initially in thermal equilibrium with each other. Is that your intention? If it is the process will be irreversible

The ideal gas law is satisfied only if a gas is at thermodynamic equilibrium (or differentially away from thermodynamic equilibrium).  That is not the case in this irreversible non-equilibrium process, so the pressures you would calculate during the irreversible process using the ideal gas law are not close to the actual forces per unit area that the gases exert on the piston (except In the final equilibrium state).

The problem is that if the piston is free to move under a finite initial pressure difference, then the resulting process is not quasi-static; which is to say, the pressures aren't well-defined quantities throughout the gases during the process, and so you can't use $-pdV$ for the work done.

Ah! That helps. So my first statement is correct (WA + WB = 0), but I cannot express the work in terms of the pressures. Thank you!
